# How do I stop scrolling from happening when I take my finger off the touchpad?

Tags: user-interface

I have recently installed 0.4, Loki, on my laptop that has a touchpad. Previously I was using version 0., Freya, and I was happy enough with it and I thought I would have basically the same user experience.

However, among a few other problems, one "feature" I am finding frustrating is that it seems that scrolling works differently. I'm not sure the term for this behaviour, and I'm sorry if my description is lacking.

If I open a text file, and I scroll down, when I take my finger off the touchpad, the document will keep moving. How fast I am scrolling determines how fast it keeps scrolling. It's as if I can "flick" the scrolling behaviour.

To be blunt, I hate this behaviour. I scroll down to a particular part of the text, take my finger off the touchpad, and then the text keeps moving so that I have to adjust my position again... and then it moves again...

I want it so that when I take my finger off the touchpad, scrolling comes to a complete stop. There should be absolutely no motion unless I am actively moving things.

How do I get this behaviour in Loki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Kinetic scrolling and it's a toolkit feature. It cannot be disabled.

However you can avoid it by bringing your fingers to a complete stop before you remove them from the trackpad. Kinetic scrolling only happens when you make a flicking gesture.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that this can not be disabled. I tried stopping moving my fingers before removing them from the trackpad (before asking the question), but that solution does not work, because this feature is sensitive to the slightest motions. Even when I intend to come to a complete stop, slight motions when lifting my finger cause scrolling to occur. I'm not willing to learn a delicate procedure for moving my hands, so, I've given up on Elementary OS, and switched to Ubuntu Mate.